# Trace on Tkinter StringVar to change label

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue with the following code snippet in Python (version 3.9) that should change a label's text based on an entry widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

def change_labels():
    print(currency.get())  # for debugging tracing
    print('1')             # for debugging tracing
    lbl_electricity['text'] = "Electricity Price (" + currency.get() + "/kWh)"


gui_present = tk.Tk()

currency = tk.StringVar()
currency.set('USD')  # sets initial value of currency

lbl_electricity = tk.Label(gui_present, text="Electricity Price (" + currency.get() + "/kWh)")
lbl_electricity.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.03, height=25, width=175)
# displays "Electricity Price (USD/kWh)" initially as required

input_currency = tk.Entry(gui_present, textvariable=currency)
input_currency.insert(0, currency.get())  # sets the entry widget to display the initial value "USD"
input_currency.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.03, width=40, height=20)

currency.trace("w", change_labels)

gui_present.mainloop()
```

The idea of the program is obviously that if I type EUR into the entry widget, the text of the label changes to

```
"Electricity Price (EUR/kWh)"
```

However, the function `change_labels()` is never executed if I type something into the entry widget (neither '1' nor the current value of currency is printed in the console). If I, just for testing purposes, remove the trace and the `text` property of the label, and put `currency` as textvariable for both widgets, the update works. But not via the update function I'd like to combine the value of `currency` with additional text.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try to execute the script in a console/terminal and see whether there is error shown?

Comment: The issue seems to be that despite typing something into the entry widget, the value of ```currency``` does not change.
I added a tk.button to the program that calls a simple function doing only
```print(currency.get())``` and regardless what is written in the entry widget, this stays at "USD".

Comment: If you execute the script in a console, you should get error shown in the console because the callback of `trace()` expect arguments, but `change_labels()` does not define any argument.  Try changing function definition to `def change_labels(*args)`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help. Since the value of ```currency``` remains the same despite me typing into the widget, ```trace``` never calls upon its callback, hence no error in the console. I'm sure the problem rests between chair and screen and I made a very stupid mistake somewhere, but I am unable to find it...

Comment: I have tested your code with the mentioned change and it works.

Comment: Thanks, I made a fresh script and there it works too with the mentioned change... OK, there seems to be a really well-hidden error in my code. I'll go on an investigative mission. Thanks for your help.